# searching source code got messed up because extra spaces between words

Tags: regex, notepad++

I was told to add some text to an existing paragraph on a webpage. I opened the corresponding file and copied some of existing text and searched for it in the source code. Search found nothing and I was going nuts. It turned out in the source code some of the words had extra spaces between them and since this wasn't displayed in the browser it screwed up searching for them in the code.

Anyone have tips to avoid this? For example is there a way to ignore white spaces, perhaps using regular expressions? It should be simple to add a sentence of text but I ended up using the design view in Dreamweaver.

Comment: Do you want to do that dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using regular expressions, you can search for multiple spaces `using +a +pattern +like +this` by putting a `+` following each space, which will instruct the search to look for one or more.